# Android app does not install with intent.action.VIEW

Tags: android

When I add an intent filter (to enable Google to crawl my app content and allow users to enter my app from search results) then my app still runs from Android Studio on my phone but it no longer installs.

My manifest is below, I have commented out the added intent filter to make it install again, so now I get a warning that it is not indexable by Google search.
What can I do so it installs and is indexable?

This is my first app so apologies if this is obvious but I appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.somename.myappname">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <!--action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /-->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <!--category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /-->
                <!--category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /-->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <!--data android:scheme="somename"
                    android:host="myappname" /-->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ChildActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have found the solution. There should be 2 separate intent filters ...

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.mywebsite.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/myappname"  />
        </intent-filter>
```